# Is it possible to run several instances of hint in parallel?

Tags: haskell

Is there any way to start two hint interpreters and at runtime & subsequently assign smaller computations to either one or the other? When I invoke hint for a small expression (e.g. typed into a website) then, - without reliable testing -, it seems to me as if the time to start/load hint is approximately one second. If the instance is already started that second would be shaved.

The hint seems to have no function where I can start it and keep it nicely pending for later use.

(Auto)Plugins would be a further option of course but I think that is more suitable for modules and less elegant for smaller computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GHC api, which hint is implemented in terms of (the various plugin packages are, too), does not support concurrent use.

You can leave hint running, though.  It's an instance of `MonadIO`.

```
interpreterLoop :: (MonadIO m, Typeable) a => Chan ((MVar a, String)) -> InterpreterT m ()
interpreterLoop ch = do
    (mvar, command) <- liftIO $ readChan ch
    a <- interpret command $ argTypeWitness mvar
    liftIO $ putMVar mvar a
    interpreterLoop ch
  where
    argTypeWitness :: MVar a -> a
    argTypeWitness = undefined -- this value is only used for type checking, never evaluated

runInLoop :: Typeable a => Chan ((MVar a, String)) -> String -> IO a
runInLoop ch command = do
    mvar <- newEmptyMVar
    writeChan ch (mvar, command)
    takeMVar mvar
```

(I didn't test this, so I may have missed a detail or two, but the basic idea will work.)

Comment: Thanks. I assume using plugins would make a difference here since to my understanding the plugins are compiled and can afterwards run in parallel?

Comment: @JFritsch No. There's no difference in that way at all. You can load functions with hint. Once loaded, the function can be evaluated many times concurrently. It's just the loading itself that cannot be done concurrently.