# When to choose plugins and when to choose hint

Tags: haskell

I do not know what would be arguments for choosing [hint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint) over [plugins](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plugins) and vice-versa. I do not have object code but plain ascii.hs files that I want to have executed at runtime. I see that in terms of evaluation they are both pretty similar. Normally I would choose hint because it is free from features that I do not need at this time. Are there any other insights?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use plugins if you want the code to be compiled and optimized.

Comment: Originally I thought this as well. I understood/interpreted from the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628003/is-it-possible-to-run-several-instances-of-hint-in-parallel however that loading = compiling? Thus, both would compile the functions before execution?

Comment: The difference is bytecode versus native code. The plugins package produces optimized native code. hint uses the *int*erpreter.

Comment: Would there be any reason why the one or the other should be better compatible w Safe Haskell?

Comment: @JFritsch: no.  Both just pass strings or files into the GHC API, so they'll support Safe Haskell as much as your current GHC.